# Python subprocess pipes hanging with communicate()

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm having a few issues with what seems like a simple piece of code in Python using the `subprocess` module.

My goal is that I have a file in `gzip` format, I want to read that file, decompress it and run it through some other external utility which will insert it into a database.

For some reason, whenever I call the `communicate()` method on the second subprocess, my whole process hangs forever, and nothing gets inserted into my database. I'm surely doing something wrong with pipes, stdouts and stdins, but can't quite figure out what, so any help would be appreciated.

I've tried the same process with the file not compressed at all and only 1 subprocess calling the external utility, and it works great though.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd_load_resolved = "nzload -host <host> -u <user> -pw <password> -db <database> -t <table>"
cmd = Popen(["gunzip"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
nz = Popen(cmd_load_resolved.strip().split(" "), stdin=cmd.stdout, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
for raw in file_key:
    cmd.stdin.write(raw)
cmd.stdin.close() # not sure if needed, i tried without but doesn't change anything
cmd.stdout.close()
nz.communicate() # hangs forever
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I've added that to the code sample, it's a simple utility to load data into Netezza. Works fine when i'm using non compressed data. Note: this is a utility provided with Netezza, not something I wrote myself.

Comment: Not sure if that can be an issue, but did you try specifying `shell=True` for the `nz`? And what's `file_key` actually?

Comment: @favoretti file_key is actually the key of the file which is stored in Amazon S3. When I loop over it, it basically just returns the lines like if it was a regular file.